# How to set status back background color in IOS 10?

Tags: swift3, ios10

This trick no longer works in iOS 10:

```
    guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView else {
```

15

"statusBarWindow" works but not "statusBar."
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_SwiftValue 0x60800049a9a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key statusBar.'

I am looking for a swift 3 answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Please try this code...

```
   let statWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey:"statusBarWindow") as! UIView
   let statusBar = statWindow.subviews[0] as UIView
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //your required color
```

Comment: this worked great for me in iOS 10 to alter the background, but it seemed to have a global effect, even though I put this code in viewWillAppear. Ie when I navigate back to other views, the altered background color remains. I am trying to work out how to undo the background color after showing the view, or how to do change the background color in a more temporary manner..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in iOS 10 / Swift 3 by adding a colored UIView under
 the status bar of the same size. I put these lines in `viewWillAppear()`

```
let statusView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:     self.view.bounds.width, height: 20))
statusView.backgroundColor = sitchOffWhite.withAlphaComponent(0.45)
 self.view.addSubview(statusView)
```